# Reading specific words and values from a file and storing them in a dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, file-io

I want to read from a file that has this format:

> gibberish
>
> ssome gibberish
>
> more giberish
>
> gibberish (about 10 lines of garbage in total)
>
> **1 lastname firstname** 3 **9,50** 22 38 38 giberish gibberish giberish
>
> **2 lastname firstname middlename** 1 **6,50** 22 38 38 giberish giberish gibberish

And what I want is to populate a dictionary with the bolded values with the key being the first number of the line like this:

dict = { 1: ['lastname', 'firstname', '9,50'], 2: ['lastname', 'firstname middlename', '6.50']}

So far I've made this:

```
list=[0,0,0]
dict={}

def process(line):
    words = line.split()
    list[0] = words[1]
    list[1] = words[2]
    list[2] = words[4]
    dict[int(words[0])] = list  

with open('fisierIntrare.txt') as file:
    for i in xrange(10):
        file.next()
    for line in file:
        process(line)
        list=[0,0,0]        


print dict
```

It basically does what I want it to do, however it heavily relies on the file being a certain format and doesn't work well for concatenating first name with middlename in one string unles they're tied like this: firstname-middlename. The things is between the first number and the next on the line there are only names:

1 lastname firstname 3...

2 lastname firstname middlename 2...

3 lastname fisrtname middlename nextname morename namename 1...

Also how do I make the last value in each list to a float? i.e '9,50' -> 9.5 and make the dictionary like this:

dict = { 1: ['lastname', 'firstname', 9.5], 2: ['lastname', 'firstname middlename', 6.5]}

So, any ideas to make my code work like I want it to?

EDIT: The gibberish is not entirely gibberish, it can be other names or numbers, just ones that I don't want to extract. Searching by regular expressions doesn't sound like a good idea to me. For example for this file:

> John
>
> John Smith
>
> 1
>
> 9.56 (about 10 lines of garbage in total)
>
> **1 John Smith** 3 **9,50** 22 38 38 Jacob Smith John
>
> **2 John Smith Jacob** 1 **6,50** 22 38 38 Peter Jack John

I think a regular expression will return to me all names in the file while I only want the ones I bolded here. The words I seek are unique more by their positioning in the file than being of a certain pattern.

Comment: *"it heavily relies on the file being a certain format"* - that's very hard to avoid, which is why structured file formats are popular! If you're stuck with this format, you could look into whether regular expressions would help you to parse it.

Comment: See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/iR5fF1/3

Comment: Yeah, the things is those gibberish things aren't entirely gibberish, not in the sense like "#$@S%SFSER@", they can be other names or numbers, I just called them gibberish because I don't want to extract them. For exemple the file can be:

Comment: John

Smith 

John

1

9,59

**1 Smith John Jack** 3 **9,50** 4 38 38 John Johnatan 38 Jacob

As far as I know of regular expressions, it searches all words within a certain pattern, only that the words I seek are not necesarilly unique or different from the one I call giberrish.

Comment: *"the words I seek are not necesarilly unique or different from the one I call giberrish"* - well how are you ever going to achieve this, then? Note that line position can be used in a regex; the example I post above will find only the information you want, as it's anchored to the start of a line.

Comment: @jonrsharpe

Hey, yeah I just checked it, it works, thanks! 
There are just  few things I need to clear, and I don't really know how. First, names like these Johnson-Smith Jack, Johnson Smith-Jack, Jack-Smith Johnson-Jacob-John should be possible. Secondly, and less important, certain characters like the "e" in "Andrè" make the regular expression miss the word. The ceratin characters I'm having problem with are nationality specific ones like è, ă, ü. I noticed Python also can't read such characters. Any solution for this?

Comment: If you use Python 3.x, `re` uses Unicode by default. If you're stuck on 2.x, do some research on regular expressions and Unicode. If you want to include hyphens in the name matches, add them to the character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters:

1. Create a loop where every line is read and is processed.
2. Evaluate in that loop if it matches the format you want. Regular Expressions (Regex) could be used for this.
3. If the above is true, get the data for it. I'd go with regular expressions here as well.
4. Clean it up if necessary.

Regex is not too easy but very powerful. I see it as the only way to get the stuff you have here under control. You can ask separate questions on it if need be. For instance, the following *pattern* would work and match each of your lines you want (you'd not even need to skip the first 10) although you would need to do more work to get the data out them:

```
r'^\d(\s[a-zA-Z])+'
```

Comment: I made an algorithm that continues to read words from the line as long as they can't be turned into an int. But your idea was good, I just don't like regular expressions that much, and since it was the only "answer" I'm giving it accept.

Comment: Could you please give me some example code? I can't seem to figure out how to read only `string`-specified words from a file :(